# Can a 12 V LED dimmer be used with a 6 V incandescent load?

Tags: voltage, pwm, dimmer

Can a 12 V LED dimmer be used with a 6 V incandescent load?
I'd be interested in knowing what factors make such an arrangement suitable or unsuitable.

Specific example: I bought a [12 V, 60 W Dimmer Box](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Illume-Lighting-60-Watt-Dimmer-Box-with-6-ft-Connection-Cord-for-LED-Products-I-DIMBOX/204413837#product-overview) because it was reduced to $5.00 and I thought I might be able to use it to build an inexpensive microscope illumination circuit.

I suspect, but do not know, that it is a PWM dimmer. I have read that PWM dimmers can be used with incandescent bulbs. The bulb in question is 6 V, 5 A incandescent.

The instruction sheet says that it can handle 12-24 V and 5 A max. I include pictures of the front and back of the circuit board:

[image: front of circuit board]

[image: back of circuit board]

The component at Q2 has a stylized "ST" and a circle containing "03" on top line The next line is "BV32" and the last line is "GE 246".  The The IC at bottom right says "NXP", "PSMN016", "100PS", "PBm 1305 E5", "4970"

I am wondering if this will function as a dimmer in a 6 V circuit?

Comment: What does the manufacturer's spec sheet tell you? You really have more info on this than it's likely anyone else here has ...

Comment: That dimmer is designed for leds not incandescent. What does the manual say for voltage range. Or take it apart and ask detailed questions with detailed pictures.

Comment: Instruction sheet indicates 12-24V but I don't know if this is because those are the voltages which the company's systems use or if the dimmer will not function beyond this range.   I also added a picture of circuit

Comment: It PROBABLY has a reasonable chance of working IF you always start with output set to low AND you never set it to higher than the bulb can tolerate OR 5A max. || Starting at low is required due to bulb inrush current when cold. More later maybe.

Comment: Max details will help. Brand and model if known. Web link. Bulb spec.

Comment: What is written on Q2 on the upper left and carefully what is on the big TO220 IC on the right. Additionally what does the back of the board look like? You'll probably have to pull off the knob before you can pull off the board.

Comment: I will get add bulb specs tomorrow when I go into work.  I will also try the dimmer on a circuit with bulb and report back results.

Comment: The component at Q2 has a stylized "ST" and a circle containing "03" on top line  The next line is "BV32" and the last line is "GE 246"

Comment: The IC says "NXP", "PSMN016", "100PS", "PBm 1305 E5", "4970"

Comment: You should add that information into the question. That said it looks like a pwm circuit, with a low side power mosfet doing the most of the control. The z2/q2 seems to be a zener transistor regulator for the control circuit so that's going to be a limit of what's the lowest the input voltage can be.

Comment: It would be much easier to simply test the dimmer and see what is the minimum to power it up rather than disassemble the whole thing, reverse engineer the circuit and then try to calculate it.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - how is this question *not* a bog-standard "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design." situation? The OP here clearly is not doing any design work on the innards of this device and cannot be reasonably expected to provide even a partial schematic of what he's dealing with. The fact that some here might find it a fun or interesting question to answer does not unfortunately make it on-topic. I'm sure you know of other forums with 'looser' rules, since you've suggested them to others before.

Comment: @brhans `modifying their electronics for other uses` and just because someone doesn't like it also doesn't mean it's off topic

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @brhans  You are correct. I am also correct, imho :-). My point here is that there are good lessons to be learned that are of value not just to the OP but also to others. Areas of learning include incandescent light of current limited LED supply, variable supply with a greater voltage range that max allowed by load, and incandescent bulb requiring more current than supply can provide at its max brightness.  ...

Comment: ... Just as the "can I operate an X volt, y amp device on Zvolt, I amp supply" question reflects a degree of misunderstanding of supplies and loads and was brilliantly answered by Olins generic answer, this could be usefully addressed by a more generic answer.

Comment: A flag has been raised that reads: "
Mod pushing a personal opinion in SHOUTY BOLD that's directly contradicts the site guidelines. (Be a sad day for the site guidelines if this one is rejected...) " || This would be best discussed on Meta, but here's some comment from said mod. || The mods are the servants of all the people, trying to balance the aims of the owners, long term site members and newcomers. Aspects to balance include owners stated aims, general rules and guidelines re question asking and answering and new user and general be nice guidelines (and rules). This is the OP's first...\

Comment: ... question. Track down [his only answer](https://photo.stackexchange.com/a/122082/6263) so far (on SE photography) and it may help you understand the reason to not rush in to prejudging new users. (I only read this a few minutes ago). || The OP is trying to solve a real world problem. It may involve plugging things together - but not in a std way. There are design aspects in the plugging together. Importantly (IMHO) this meets the owners spec of questions with good lifetimes that attract search engine traffic (not what most think the site is about, perhaps :-) ). | Please see my answer ...

Comment: ... which addresses the points more generally. || Re SHOUTY BOLD - it's a heading to attract attention - I should have bolded it :-). It's my std way of addressing such matters. || Personal opinion - Yes. We all have one. This is consistent with what I said I'd do when the election was held. I said by all means do not vote for me if you don't like it. Most did. I far more often than not do not act on matters which go against my personal preferences. Serving ALL the people is a pain :-). !! Comments welcome (really). Raise it on Meta also if desired.

Comment: Make sure not to exceed bulb max voltage.

Comment: Is there a StackExchange site where this question is on-topic?  I could post it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Summary:**

This answer applies generically to operating incandescent loads from DC input dimmers.
In each case the points to watch are that

- bulb inrush current when cold does not cause problems,
- that both dimmer and bulb output voltage and current ratings are not exceeded,
- That dimmer input voltage specs are met.

Procedures & limits

It is likely but not certain that the dimmer will work if

- Always set to low at turnon.
- NEVER set to above the 5A, 6V output position
- Operated from a 12V supply.

---

**Detail:**

More detail re brand and model and weblink (if available) and bulb specs will help greatly.

It is likely but not certain that it will work with a 6V, 5A bulb.

AT turnon a bulb has a very low cold resistance so current drawn will be high if the dimmer is set to "high" . Starting with the dimmer at low and turning it up should allow the bulb to heat and provide a higher resistance.

Maximum bulb voltage is 6V, when 5A will be drawn.
The dimmer claims to allow 5A out. In SOME cases current out allowed may be lower at low voltages but there is a reasonable chance that 5A will be available at 6V.|

Setting the dimmer to above the 5A, 6V position may cause problems. Either the dimmer may overload rather than current limiting. Noting the 6V, 5A position and not exceeding it would be advisable.

The 12V rating MAY be an input voltage below which the dimmer will not function correctly. Operating it on a 12V supply would avoid this. Testing at Vin below 12V MAY destroy the dimmer (and may work) - unknowable.

Comment: I tried the dimmer with input voltages from 6V to 20V (the maximum of my power supply) with 5A maximum.  For voltages below 9V there was no output voltage from the dimmer at any setting.  For 9-20V the dimmer varied the output voltage from 0V to just under the input voltage.  Thanks everyone for the comments, suggestions and help.